# 90 minute isochrones in QGIS

Tags: qgis, isochrone

I recently discovered QGIS.  The software is very impressive, even if it is not always easy to know how to unlock the features.  [This](https://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/drive%20time%20isochrones/) article provides good pointers, although I can't make it work.

I am trying to draw 90 minute isochrones across borders, but am stuck: ORS cannot handle more than 60 minutes, while TravelTime Platform does not cross borders - strange in Europe.

I also tried HQGIS, but for some reason nothing happens when I click the 'Calculate isochrones' button. QNEAT3 does not function either, even if I use a road shapefile in a non-WGS84 projection.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to switch to meters instead of minutes.

So, checking something like [*"average walking speed in m per minute"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preferred_walking_speed) will provide you with a certain value.

I will probably use something like 90 meters per minute.
So, 90 minutes are approximately 8.000 meters of walking.

[This source](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-calculate-travel-time-for-any-location-in-the-world-56ce639511f) gives something like 75 meters per minute.

But be careful, which moving object you are considering, children definitely are walking slower than adults etc. The same logic may be applied for public transport, private vehicles and so on.

To create isochrones possible with the GRASS library [`v.net.iso`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/v.net.iso.html). And do not forget to switch to CRS.